# Derivative of negative exponential of increasing function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, exponential-function

Let $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ be a nondecreasing, continuously differentiable function such that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x) = \infty$. Define the function $$g(x) = \exp\left\{-f(x)\right\}.$$
It's obvious that $g(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$. But, is it also necessarily true that $g^{\prime}(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$?

At first it seems fairly obvious because the graph of $g$ appears to flatten out as $x\rightarrow\infty$, but then again I am not able to prove it. For my attempt, I first differentiate
$$g^{\prime}(x) = -f^{\prime}(x) \exp\left\{-f(x)\right\} = -\frac{f^{\prime}(x)}{\exp\left\{f(x)\right\}}\le 0,$$
the inequality holding because $f$ is nondecreasing. Then, I tried to find a lower bound and show that the lower bound converges to $0$. One natural lower bound can be obtained by using the known inequality $1+x \le e^x$: $$-\frac{f^{\prime}(x)}{1+f(x)}\le -\frac{f^{\prime}(x)}{\exp\left\{f(x)\right\}},$$
but this is way too crude (since it only works if $f$ increases faster than $f^{\prime})$. For example, if $f(x) = e^x$ then this lower bound would not work.

I couldn't think of a nondecreasing function $f$ where $f^{\prime}(x)$ increases faster than $\exp\left\{f(x)\right\}$. Does such a function exist? A sufficient condition would be to find an increasing function $f$ such that $f^{\prime}(x) \ge \exp\left\{f(x)\right\}$ for all $x$ sufficiently large. The only function that I could think of being a potential problem is $f(x) = -\log(C-x)$ for $C\ge 0$, but this function isn't defined on all of $[0,\infty)$.

Long story short, can this be proven in general or are there counterexamples?

Comment: You could consider $f(x)$ given by $\log(1 + x) + k(x)$ where $k(x)$ is given by $k(0) = 0$ and $k'(x)$ being a series of tall triangular spikes, where there is a spike at each $n \in \mathbb N$ of width $1/n^3$ and height $n$, and $k'(x) = 0$ elsewhere (so you integrate this to get $k(x)$). This is constructed so that $k(x)$ is bounded and hence asymptotically doesn't affect $f(x)$, but $k'(x)$ is asymptotically unbounded above. Basically, a function can briefly have a very very large derivative while still looking flat from far away.

Comment: In this particular example, the derivative isn't smooth due to the triangular spikes. For an example with a smooth derivative, I assume that you can give a similar construction but instead round out the triangles? @IzaakvanDongen

Comment: Yes, you could use what's called a [bump function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function). The usual example is to use $\exp(1/(x^2-1))$ shapes instead of triangles. Aside from that very little would change, since we can bound the areas of each bump similarly.